# Save serial data output to hourly files python

Tags: python, cron, serial-port, raspberry-pi3

I have a python script running on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ which is reading data from a barometer connected to the serial port. The script works well and captures 10 Hz data from the barometer (10 lines of data every second).

I have an @reboot cron job which starts the script whenever the Pi boots up.
A filename is generated at boot.

```
import io
import serial
import sys
import time
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

#serial port
port = "/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_US232R_FT1TSTRU-if00-port0"

#try to connect to barometer at 9600bps:
ser=serial.Serial(port, 9600, timeout=1, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)

# File storage
SSD_path="/media/pi/USBDRIVE/"
filename=time.strftime('barometer-%Y-%m-%d-%H%M.dat')
path=SSD_path + filename

#write data to file on SSD
ser.write(b'*0100E6\r\n')

with open(path, 'w+') as f:
    while True:
        line = str(ser.readline())
        f.writelines([line.strip(), " t = %s \n " % (datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-5])])
```

I would like to have the script generate a new filename every hour instead of the ever growing single file situation that I currently have.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Basically you just need replace the `while True` with a loop that will stop after running for an hour. Afterwards, a new filename can be generated, the file opened, and the hour loop restarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your hardware, so have commented out parts of your code dealing with it in the code below with `##`. It shows how to implement what I suggested in a comment — namely generate an output filename, run the data capturing loop for an hour, then rinse and repeat.

```
import io
import os
import random  # for testing
##import serial
import sys
import time
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

TIME_INTERVAL = 3600  # Seconds.

#serial port
port = "/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_US232R_FT1TSTRU-if00-port0"

#try to connect to barometer at 9600bps:
##ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600, timeout=1, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
##                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)

# File storage
##SSD_path = "/media/pi/USBDRIVE/"
SSD_path = r"C:\vols\Files\PythonLib\Stack Overflow"
#write data to file on SSD
##ser.write(b'*0100E6\r\n')

print('running')
while True:
    filename = time.strftime('barometer-%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S.dat')
    path = os.path.join(SSD_path, filename)

    with open(path, 'w+') as f:
        start = time.time()
        while (time.time() - start) < TIME_INTERVAL:
##            line = str(ser.readline())
            line = str(random.randint(0, 100))
            time.sleep(.1)
##            f.writelines([line.strip(), " t = %s \n " % (datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-5])])
            f.writelines([line.strip(), " t = %s \n " % (datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-5])])
```

Comment: @martineu thanks very much. It worked like a charm.